# Chain two jquery methods?

Tags: jquery

I clone the first li:

```
var r = $('#myList li:first').clone(true);
```

I then remove the selected option:

```
$('option:selected', r).remove();
```

Is there a way to chain this? As in:

```
var r = $('#myList li:first').clone(true).('option:selected').remove();
```

Comment: That part wil fail : `.('option:selected').`

Comment: you'd need `.find('option:selected')`, since `.('option')` is a totally invalid function call. there's no function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context selector is just a shortcut for `find()`, so you can use that instead.

```
$('#myList li:first').clone(true).find('option:selected').remove();
```

of course, that doesn't return the clone, but the removed option, to return the clone you can do

```
var c = $('#myList li:first').clone(true).find('option:selected').remove().end();
```

Comment: @BenM - Uhm, exactly ?

Comment: @adaneo - Uhm, where does he expliciltly state that the `<select>` element is in the cloned `<li>`?

Comment: @BenM - By using the context selector it's pretty clear that it is, did you read the question ?

Comment: My bad, sorry, I didn't see the context selector in his second `$()` call. Long, hot day in the office.

Answer (score 0):

If its 'oneliner' you are looking for then this
`$('option:selected', $('#myList li:first').clone(true)[0]).remove();`
should do it.

You can't have them chained like it's in your example.